Build a spring boot based webhook consumer service
I have a requirement to build a spring boot based webhook service which can consume request bodies in either JSON or XML in any format.
For eg: we onboard a customer who already has a fixed JSON format for generated events which they would like to send as it is to this new webhook service endpoint. The endpoint should be intelligent enough to understand that since this request came from a particular customer (probably identified by some unique consumer id in header or token), it would be in a particular format which then needs to be mapped to a common cannonical format.
Tomorrow if a new customer is onboarded who sends events in a completely different format, just by setting up the transformation template, this new service should be able to parse this new customers request also to the common cannonical format.
Could you please provide suggestions on how this can be implemented?

I'm not sure if you have added the spring-integration tag deliberately, but you indeed can do that dynamic routing using respective Spring Integration components and configuration. See documentation if that makes sense for you: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/router/dynamic-routers.html.
You even can add new logic based on a new format without restarting an application, but that's much broader subject which we may not solve just over here on StackOverflow.
